# what is wrong in this code after data in this view?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save values in respected model by it shows error like this:

File "/home/bikash/tt/nascent/nascent_backend/home/views.py", line 72, in dispatch
user.save()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'

```
class CheckoutSessionView(TemplateView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            price1 = request.body            
            price2 = price1.decode('utf-8')
            price11 = json.loads(price2)
            print(price11)
            print(type(price11),990, price11['json_data']['priceId'])
            password1 = price11['json_data']['password1']
            password2 = price11['json_data']['password2']
            name = price11['json_data']['name']
            company = price11['json_data']['company']
            contact = price11['json_data']['contact']
            email = price11['json_data']['email']

            user = User(name = name, username = company, email = email, contact=contact )
            if password1==password2:
                user = user.set_password(password1)
                user.save()            
            company = Company(title = company)
            company.owner = user
            company.save()
            company.members.add(user)
```

how can i save this?

Comment: please what wrong write comment to discussion.

Comment: You’re mutating the user variable so it is no longer a user object. You can’t use save on that.

Comment: `user = user.set_password()` should just be `user.set_password()`

Comment: I added this as an actual answer if you could accept @BikashSaud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mutate the user object with `user = user.set_password()` as set_password doesn't return a user object therefore the `save()` method is no longer available.

Instead, just call the method without assigning it to a variable.

```
if password1 == password2:
    user.set_password(password1)
    user.save()
```

This will stop the Attribute error.